# ¿Cómo validar un único checkbox?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Estoy haciendo un juego simple con JavaScript sobre piedra, papel o tijera, y tengo que usar un checkbox para habilitar la opción de que la máquina solo juegue con papel y piedra (sin tijera) pero solo la computadora. No me anda y no encuentro el error, les paso el codigo:

```js
function elijepc() {
  if (document.getElementByName('sintijera').checked) {
    alert("modo sin tijera activado")
    let op = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    switch (op) {
      case 0:
        return "piedra";
        break;
      case 1:
        return "papel";
        break;
      default:
        ("-");
    }
  } else {
    let op = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    switch (op) {
      case 0:
        return "piedra";
        break;
      case 1:
        return "papel";
        break;
      case 2:
        return "tijera";
        break;
      default:
        ("-");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="sintijera" id="notijera" value="notijera">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema debe residir en el uso del método getElementByName(), ya que el mismo devuelve una lista de objetos, no devuelve un único objeto. Lo mejor sería utilizar el método getElementById, que sí devuelve un objeto.

Puedes revisar lo que te digo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

Comment: Luis , recordar que no existe un método `getElementByName` , el que retorna una lista es el método `getElementsByName` con un `s` adicional.

Answer (score 0):

El código contiene algunos fallos que debes corregir:

1. No es `getElementByName` sino `getElementsByName` (elements con s)
2. `getElementsByName` devuelve una lista con los elementos, sería mejor que usaras `getElementById` o `querySelector` para seleccionar un único elemento
3. No asocias la función `elijepc` al checkbox, por lo que no se ejecuta (aunque esto puede ser porque no has incluido todo tu código)

Una vez corregidos esos errores, el código ya funciona bien:

```js
function elijepc() {
  if (document.getElementById('notijera').checked) {
    alert("modo sin tijera activado")
    let op = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    switch (op) {
      case 0:
        return "piedra";
        break;
      case 1:
        return "papel";
        break;
      default:
        ("-");
    }
  } else {
    let op = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    switch (op) {
      case 0:
        return "piedra";
        break;
      case 1:
        return "papel";
        break;
      case 2:
        return "tijera";
        break;
      default:
        ("-");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="sintijera" id="notijera" value="notijera" onclick="elijepc()">
```